How to provide sysdate pattern in Copy file command in Snowflake
I have below Copy Files command in Snowflake which is working fine. But currently the date 20240822 is hardcoded in this pattern and i want to provide sysdate so that it can copy the files with sysdate folder daily.
COPY FILES
INTO @STG_RAW_DPT_UPLOAD_ARCHIVE
FROM @STG_RAW_DPT_UPLOAD
PATTERN = '^dpt20240822.*'


Something like PATTERN = CONCAT('^dpt', REPLACE(CURRENT_DATE(), '-'), '.*')? Not sure it is possible to declare it this way though.

I tried few other ways with using || and Concat but it didn't worked out

Hm, can you please try to define a variable like SET target_pattern = CONCAT('^dpt', REPLACE(SysDate(), '-', ''), '.*'); and then use it like PATTERN = :target_pattern?

SET target_pattern is not working and throwing error 000002 (0A000): Unsupported feature 'assignment from non-constant source expression'.

OK, so it is even more tricky.

dont understand why Snowflake makes that very complex

I think you need to do this in a Stored Procedure (or code block) and dynamically construct the COPY INTO statement

Using session variable: SET p = (SELECT  CONCAT('''^dpt', TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYYMMDD'), '.*''')); COPY FILES INTO @STG_RAW_DPT_UPLOAD_ARCHIVE FROM @STG_RAW_DPT_UPLOAD PATTERN = $p;

If your copy command fits under 256 characters, you could store that to a session variable and execute that instead
set stmt = 'copy files into @that_stage from @this_stage pattern='||$$'$$||to_char(current_date,'.*dptyyyymmdd.*'||$$'$$);

select $stmt;

execute immediate $stmt;


i am getting error now Session variable '$STMT' does not exist' when i try to use your logic in create task . When i run this without task it works. What might be the issue ?

You'd have to create your task as a scripting block using scripting variables instead of session variables.  See here for example https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task#:~:text=Procedural%20logic%20using%20Snowflake%20Scripting%C2%B6. You current question is well defined so let's not muddy it. I suggest asking a new question in context of tasks.

thanks i will ask new question which is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78906485/session-variable-stmt-does-not-exist-in-create-task-in-snowflake

can you please provide answer to that new question as you already mentioned here
